# Getting error while trying to debug chrome cast custom receiver

Tags: chromecast, receiver, custom-receiver

I am getting an error below while trying to debug the custom receiver.

```
cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
```

This is the error when I execute the up statement;

> VM213:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLevelValue' of undefined
>       at :1:22

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging#chrome

How can I deal with this?